# Add a new product in dynamic 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'm using Dynamic 365 trial version. For learning purpose, I want to create a new product.

For this I navigated as follow.

```
Sales => Collateral => Products
```

But I can't find option to add a new product or product family.

[image]

Is this options not available in trail version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have one of the following security roles or equivalent permissions: System Administrator, System Customizer, Sales Manager, Vice President of Sales, Vice President of Marketing, or CEO-Business Manager.

If you are Office 365 Global Admin but not System Administrator in CRM go to Settings - Security - Users - Open your user and click Promote to Admin button on the ribbon

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the proper view. You should go to Settings -> Product catalogue -> Products and Families. There you will be able to add and edit your products and all the related sales stuff like Pricelists or Unit Groups
 [image: Products catalogue]

Answer (score 0):

You can create products only in base language. So switch CRM interface language to base one in personal settings and then navigate back to product view. You will see add new product button there.

Microsoft made this limitation because now products can have multilanguage names.